# Reduce memory usage working with very large csv files

Tags: python, csv, memory-management, type-conversion

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to write code that will allow me to reduce memory usage when working with very large csv files, by converting the datatype of the columns.
Applying those few things I learned, I wrote the following code:

```py
# They are lines of code that I wrote by adapting the code learned in the following lesson:
# https://www.udemy.com/course/corso-python-e-data-science/learn/lecture/13091796#content

# To test the code I use a csv file relating to the passengers embarked on Titanic.
# I should had downloaded it from the following website,
# but I'm not sure because I didn't pin the URL when I downloaded it:
# https://github.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/blob/master/titanic.csv

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

xInt_Types = ["int64", "int32", "int16", "int8", "uint64", "uint32", "uint16", "uint8"]
xFloat_Types = ["float64", "float32", "float16"]

# The user needs to indicate the CSV file with the data he wants to work on
xPath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
xFile = pd.read_csv(xPath)

# I store the label assigned to each column of the CSV file
xColumnName = xFile.columns

# This Function allows you to calculate the weight of the data contained in a DataFrame
def f_Size(xDataFrame):
    xSomma = 0
    for xDataType in ["float16", "float32", "float64", "uint8", "uint16", "uint32", "uint64", "int8", "int16", "int32", "int64", "object"]:
        xSel_DataType = xDataFrame.select_dtypes(include=[xDataType])
        xTot_Bytes = xSel_DataType.memory_usage(deep=True)
        xMedia_Bytes = xSel_DataType.memory_usage(deep=True).mean()
        xMedia_Megabytes = xMedia_Bytes/1024**2
        xSomma += xMedia_Megabytes
    return xSomma

# This function allows you to summarize the main characteristics of different number formats
def f_Info(xInt_Types, xFloat_Types):
    for xInt in xInt_Types:
        print(np.iinfo(xInt))
    for xFlt in xFloat_Types:
        print(np.finfo(xFlt))

#This function calculates the weight of the data contained in the column of a DataFrame
def f_M_U(xPandas_Data):
    if isinstance(xPandas_Data, pd.DataFrame):
        xMem_Usage_b = xPandas_Data.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
    else:
        xMem_Usage_b = xPandas_Data.memory_usage(deep=True)
    return xMem_Usage_b

# This function allows you to retrieve the characteristics of each object attribute (column) of the csv file
def f_CSV_Attr(xFile, xColumnName):
    for xCol in xColumnName:
        xFile_Object = xFile.select_dtypes(include=["object"]).copy()
        print(xFile_Object.describe())

#To save memory I'll transform:
     #Int64 to Int32 and so on
     #Float64 into Float32 and so on
     #Object into Categories

def f_Zip(xFile, xInt_Types, xFloat_Types, xColumnName):
    xOptimize_File = xFile.copy()
    # In xOptimize_File we replace the original columns with the converted ones
    for xCol in xColumnName:
        if xFile[xCol].dtypes in xInt_Types:
            for i in xInt_Types:
                xFile_Int = xFile.select_dtypes(include=[i])
                xConvertedInt = xFile_Int.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast="unsigned")
                xOptimize_File[xConvertedInt.columns] = xConvertedInt
        elif xFile[xCol].dtypes in xFloat_Types:
            for f in xFloat_Types:
                xFile_Float = xFile.select_dtypes(include=[f])
                xConvertedFloat = xFile_Float.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast="float")
                xOptimize_File[xConvertedFloat.columns] = xConvertedFloat
        else:
            xNum_Unique = len(xFile[xCol].unique())
            xNum_Total = len(xFile[xCol])
            if xNum_Unique / xNum_Total < 0.5:
                xConverted_Object = xFile[xCol].astype("category")
                #xOptimize_File[xConverted_Object.columns] = xConverted_Object # This generates an error
                xOptimize_File[xFile[xCol]] = xConverted_Object # This also doesn't work :-(
            else:
                xConverted_Object = xFile[xCol]

    print(xOptimize_File)
    return xOptimize_File

print('The weight of the selected file is equal to:', f_Size(xFile))
xOptimize_File = f_Zip(xFile, xInt_Types, xFloat_Types, xColumnName)
print('The weight of the converted file is equal to:', f_Size(xOptimize_File))
```

I'm trying to reduce memory usage and the code I wrote isn't working.

Comment: Using Panda isn't a good idea for optimising the memory usage; `pd.read_csv` parses the whole file into RAM... With a big enough CSV input, the code is bound to crash

Comment: Thanks Fravadona, I'll remember that. I completed a Udemy course and to verify that I understood what I was supposed to learn, I wrote these lines of code (as an exercise). I'd like to understand where I went wrong to identify what I didn't understand about the course and learn more

Comment: Hi. What problems have you had with memory consumption?

Comment: Hi Zach, I wrote this code to verify what I understood from a lesson... little I would say, given the results

Answer (score 1):

The fastest, lowest-use memory, and by-far simplest option will be to use the csv module's reader: it iterates the input CSV row-by-row and returns a list of strings for each row.  From that list of strings simply cast them as the types you expect.

Given this input:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
81.23,23938,false,ZUITO
67.57,27480,false,JLMAU
97.55,63965,false,SAVPW
53.15,23907,false,NTZLZ
14.90,29321,false,IQUVA
65.27,45452,true,MLUYP
12.66,81050,true,YLWBC
56.12,39627,true,CCRAW
44.83,18004,true,ASSOP
77.43,23267,true,SXOLU
```

```py
import csv

MyRow = tuple[float, int, bool, str]

rows: list[MyRow] = []
with open("input.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # discard header
    for row in reader:
        rows.append(
            (
                float(row[0]),
                int(row[1]),
                row[2] == "true",
                row[3],
            )
        )

print(rows)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    (81.23, 23938, False, "ZUITO"),
    (67.57, 27480, False, "JLMAU"),
    (97.55, 63965, False, "SAVPW"),
    (53.15, 23907, False, "NTZLZ"),
    (14.9, 29321, False, "IQUVA"),
    (65.27, 45452, True, "MLUYP"),
    (12.66, 81050, True, "YLWBC"),
    (56.12, 39627, True, "CCRAW"),
    (44.83, 18004, True, "ASSOP"),
    (77.43, 23267, True, "SXOLU"),
]
```

I like type hints, so I created MyRow to help ensure I use the correct castings, and the correct number of castings, to match my expectations.  The type hints have nothing to do with how the values will be evaluated/casted at run time.  Incorrect types for Col1 and Col2 will throw a ValueError if they turn out not to be a float and/or an int.

Comment: Thx Zach, interesting code. I'll save it on a file in case I need it in the future